# How to Change the color of carousel icon boostrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

Im using bootstrap 4 but can't change the carousel icone color

```
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" style="color:blue" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
     </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you the next and prev icon try this:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='green' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M4 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }

  .carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='green' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }
```

Here we are directly going into the svg file, and then we change the fill color